# How do I utilize filters and child elements in Google Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Working on an Android app that is using the new Firebase Database framework. It has data objects that are modeled like this:
[image]
Where the Top parent (1234-4321) is the 'chat room', the data object are the 'chat messages', and the numbered items (0, 1, 2) are the 'individual message'.

I am able to get the entire Database without any trouble and read it via listeners:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
myRef.addChildEventListener(this);
myRef.addValueEventListener(this);
```

And I am able to get a single child in this fashion:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
String id = "1234-4321";
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child(id);
myRef.addChildEventListener(this);
myRef.addValueEventListener(this);
```

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get multiple objects of the same type. What I mean is, a user will be able to get More than one chat room (IE, both '1234-4321' and '1234-4432'), but the only way I can see to do this is either to:

1) loop through the onChildAdded or onDataChange listeners, separate out the items by matching the String ids, and updating them. This is, however, extremely inefficient as I am parsing the entire Database, which could be quite large

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    if(dataSnapshot != null){
        try {
            ChatObjectV2 objectV2 = (ChatObjectV2) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            //Check here for ids and loop through everything
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

or

2) To add a specific child, but if I try to add more children it is going 'deeper' into the nested object when I want it to go 'wider'.

```
//This won't work because it is going 'deeper' instead of 'wider'
String id = "1234-4321";
String id2 = "1234-4432";
Query myQuery = myRef.child(id).child(id2);
```

And then loop through in the listener the same way, but, I would need to create a different DatabaseReference for every chat room, which is horribly inefficient.

It looks like the solution is probably to use [filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#filtering_data), but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to utilize them in the existing FirebaseDatabase and DatabaseReference objects. Does anyone have any idea how to make a filter work with regards to the data schema / model I have listed here?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try to explain you the basic use of filtering in these examples:

**//getting first two chat room**s

```
Query chatRoomsQuery = databaseReference.limitToLast(2);
```

**//getting last two chat rooms**

```
Query chatRoomsQuery = databaseReference.limitToFirst(2)
```

**//getting all active id**

```
Query chatRoomsQuery = databaseReference.orderByChild("active").equalTo(true);
```

This is just a basic sample I would encourage you to go through [this blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/11/firebase-now-with-more-querying.html). Which explains advanced queries amazingly.

Alternatively, you can also go through [these docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-ordered-data). They are different than what you shared.

Do let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Read through them and they were definitely helpful, but none of the samples would work for what I am trying to do. I guess the real goal here is to add multiple where clauses to my query (IE Where  id = 123 OR where id = 321), which I don't really see anywhere in the documentation. Is this something you have heard done before or know how it could be done in firebase (Java/ Android)?

Comment: So when you are going to use those two ids. Let's say ID1 and ID2 .. what is the common connection between them ? How will they be related ?

Comment: The relation would just be that that their ID would be either in the sending or receiving ID somewhere in the chat room as: For example, Customer A has 2 'chat rooms' open, one started by them and one not started by them. Customer A will therefore have their ID in one of the 2 fields: ("sentBy" or "receivedBy").

Comment: So you will check that Customer A is in which chat room under sentBy id or receivedBy id . It ill be one of two right ? and you want to know what is the **id of that chat room** . Am I getting it right?

Comment: Pretty much. If I can confirm that Customer A is in the chat room either by the sentBy or receivedBy, then I want to pull that entire object as it will be used. If CustomerA is NOT in the chat room, it can be skipped entirely as it is not relevant. The goal is to figure out a way to add a query of some sort to narrow the results based on those parameters.

Comment: Right! **So I have already handled a similar case in my answer here I will modify accordingly have a look : **                                                                                               `Query chatRoomsQuery = databaseReference.orderByChild("sentBy").equalTo("CustomerAName/ID");`                                                                                                                                Did you realize I just narrowed down your query. Now the reference will be set to only that object where **sentBy** == "CustomerAName/ID" ;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124449/discussion-between-nishant-dubey-and-silmarilos).