# Search for a specific value in all children in a list in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database on Firebase:
[image: firebase database]

I want to return a search on users if there is any with the true type.

```
mDatabaseReference.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("type")) {//I need the verification here.
                //action
            } else {
                //action
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```

Thank you in advance for your attention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What **you are looking for is a filtered quer**y like this:

```
Query filterQuery = databaseReference.orderByChild("type").equalTo(true);
```

You can also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735586/how-do-i-utilize-filters-and-child-elements-in-google-firebase-database/39735941#39735941) answer for more examples about filtering data and have a look at [these docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query).

*Do let me know if this points you in right direction.*

**EDIT:**

You can check for null by putting this condition in a if statement *in **onDataChange***

```
dataSnapshot.getValue() != null
```

Comment: Yes, I am using this filter to pass the query to my adapter. But before sending me the query there I need to know if its return is not empty or null. How do I check this?

Comment: Check the edited answer that is what you should do to check for null in datasnapshot.